# How can I draw a parallelipiped and draw a filled circle in its center

Tags: opengl, cube

How can I draw a parallelipiped and draw a filled circle in its center. Please explain the maths involved in it.. Currently I am trying to achieve it using OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the 3 vectors that define the parallelipiped.  Its center is half the sum of these three vectors.  Your circle will have the same center as the parallelpiped.  Find the closest edge of the parallelpiped from the center point.  This is your radius.